# How to know the number of contacts per Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, contactbuilder, sfmc-business-unit, multi-org

I am on a multi org instance.
From the Parent BU, I would like to know the number of contacts per child business unit.

For the moment, I have not found a solution other than filtering on the attribute.

Is there any other way to know the distribution of my contacts?

Thanks

Davy_C

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a great way to do this. You would have to build a custom solution for when your subscribers entered, appending an attribute to their record upon entry. You could then build a table to match back to their SubscriberID. This isn't a perfect solution, because it would only capture when a customer first entered a particular business unit, and wouldn't account for being in Multiple BUs. For example, if I have multiple BUs with overlapping subscribers, they technically could be attributable to either BU.

Answer (score 0):

I don't that there is an OOTB way to get contacts count per BU. However, you can generate the total Contact Count Report in Analytics Builder to get the count of billable contacts in the Account.

Path:Analytics builder--> Reports --> Contact count

Salesforce help link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_contacts_counts.htm&type=5